# Q: Begin a row from the first non-null value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

Problem: 
I have a data table with the price of different references each year. Some references are bought since 2004, others since 2002...

[image]

However, I want something like this where all the prices begin at the same point called in my example year 1 that is the first year where the company bought a reference (so this is the first non-null value in the row), year 2 is the second year....

[image: [What I want]

The main difficulty is that I can't use VBA (even if I could, I don't see how) and I have to do this for more than thousands rows.

How can I do to automatize this?

I tried to get the first value of each rows with this:

```
=INDEX(A2:V2;MATCH(TRUE;A2:V2<>"";0))
```

But I don't know how to get the values after.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what the correlation is between `YEAR1` etc in your desired results and the years in the data. Please refer to [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The tile of the question has absolutely nothing to do with what you are asking for, so this question is totally unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear, I tried to edit it to be more understandable. Let me know if it's still not clear!

Comment: It's clear now, but you have forgotten to include your own attempt.

Comment: Done! Sorry again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your requirements, I think it would be easier (in terms of finding the "next" column, to find the first filled column number, instead of the first value.  Then you can increment that.

```
=IF(INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(2:2)*COLUMN(2:2),1)-1+COLUMNS($A:A))="","",INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(2:2)*COLUMN(2:2),1)-1+COLUMNS($A:A)))
```

To find the first column number that contains a number (I assume the first column is text, if not, some changes may be needed):

```
1/ISNUMBER(2:2)*COLUMN(2:2),1)-1+COLUMNS($A:A)
```

will return an array of `{DIV/0!, n, …}` where `n` is a column number where the cell contains a number

The `AGGREGATE` function will return the smallest number in this array, ignoring errors, and that is the first filled column.

We then increment this as we fill right with the `COLUMNS($A:A)`.

And we need the `IF` statement because when `INDEX` finds an empty cell, it will return a zero instead of a blank.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!!!! Thank you so much, the explanation is also very clear!

Answer (score 1):

I got something for you:

```
Sub Delete_blanks()
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Select the data and run the macro it should work for you.

Any questions or problems let me know.

Comment: You can do it in one line `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`

Comment: You missed, in the question: *"The main difficulty is that I can't use VBA"*

Comment: As Ron said , I specified that I can't use VBA unfortunately...

Comment: In addition, your solution does **NOT** provide the requested result. It removes blanks after the first entry, and those should be maintained.